# How to make program end when specific line of redirected file is read

Tags: c, arrays, io-redirection

Ok, so I'm going to explain my program.
It takes a text file that's setup as such: in pairs, first line being the title of an experiment, and the second line being 10 numbers separated by spaces. It saves the first lines of pairs in `*experiments` and the second lines of pairs in `data`. The last line is `*** END ***` which is what it's supposed to end with.

For some reason `*** END ***` doesn't end the program. Any ways I can fix this? I'm assuming it's because fgets gives `str` blank spaces (99 chars total) so that the string in quotes will never be equal to str?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int var;
    int i=0,j,k;
    char seps[] = " ";
    char *experiments[20];
    int data[10][20];
    char str[100]; // make sure that this size is enough to hold the single line
    char *ptr, *token;
    int no_line=1;


    while(fgets(str,100,stdin) != NULL && strcmp(str,"*** END ***"))
    {
        if(no_line % 2 == 0)
        {
            k=0;
            token = strtok (str, seps);
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                sscanf (token, "%d", &var);
                data[i][k++] = var;
                token = strtok (NULL, seps);
            }
            i++;
            /*read integer values from the string "str" using sscanf, sscanf can be called in a loop with %d untill it fails */
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = strdup(str);
            experiments[i] = ptr;
            /*strore string in your variable "experiments" , before copying allocate a memory for the each entry */
        }
        no_line++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%s",experiments[j]);
        for(k=0;k<10;k++)
            {
            printf("%d ",data[j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using `valgrind` to help debugging.

Comment: @Mauren Don't you mean `clang`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits well, I've never played with `clang`, but I find `valgrind` very valuable when dealing with corrupted memory-related bugs.

Comment: @Mauren This looks like a non-memory related problem (well, maybe not if illegal memory access is in that category).  `clang` is great!  Finds many problems `gcc` misses.

Comment: @FiddlingBits but `valgrind` also warns for non-initialized variables and other error-prone stuff. I'm gonna take a look at `clang`.

Comment: @Mauren `valgrind` is not compatible with the latest Mac OS.  I wish it was though.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `i` here ...

```
int i,j,k;
```

... and using it here ...

```
data[i][k++] = var;
```

Nowhere do you initialize `i`.  Also, why does `data` need to be a 2D array?  Can't it just be a 1D array?

```
int data[10];

...

data[k++] = var;
```

Comment: `data` and `*experiments` cannot be changed. And I declared i=0 but my program doesn't do anything now, though it doesn't crash like before

Comment: If `i` is now `0`, this line is causing a problem: `for(j=0;j<i;j++)`.  The loop is never executed.

Comment: damn for some reason i must have deleted old code by accident because i thought i had already declared i and incremented it. going to fix that quick

Comment: So I thought i fixed it, however now there's a new problem, look in title for input and output

Comment: fixed it some more, but now `*** END ***` isn't ending my program. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From this code, int `i` seems to be declared, but not initialized?

```
data[i][k++] = var;
```

It may be helpful to use Eclipse or Code Block IDE to try small testable codes because it has all sorts of syntax and error checking features.

Comment: Nothing beats `clang`.